# Adding a common, background box with different colors by column, to bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am learning bootstrap now, and am trying to make a simple website. I created a row with 3 columns (sizes: 3,6,3), each with it's own text elements. I wanted the first and last column to be colored in red and the middle in grey. I used a background-color in css to do this, but I see that the color envelopes just around the text elements. Is there any way to quickly add a bar of different colors but same height? The [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWu2X.png) may help better understand the problem. I could create a new bootstrap row with a bar and add it behind them, but wanted to know if there's a simpler solution. The html and css are as follows.

```
<div class="aboutbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="leftbar">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <h3> 231 </h3>
                    <p>Enthusiasts</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="middlebar">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <h3><a href="#"> Kanye West</a></h3>
                    <p> Kanye Omari West is an American hip hop recording artist, record producer, rapper, fashion designer, and entrepreneur.West is one of the best-selling artists of all time, having sold more than 32 million albums and 100 million digital downloads worldwide.
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="rightbar">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <ul style="list-style:none;">
                        <li class="emphasis"> Follow </li>
                        <li> Events </li>
                        <li> Blog </li>
                    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
    .leftbar .col-xs-3 {
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
}

.middlebar .col-xs-6 {
    background-color:grey;
    color:white;
}

.rightbar .col-xs-3 {
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the same height to columns is a quite common problem. 
I use a jquery plugin that force the same height to all columns of the row.

http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

Comment: Thanks Cesare! Appreciate the help!

Comment: YOu are welcome, if you have solved your problem, please accept the answer.